NotImplementedError: Sub-geometries may have coordinate sequences, but multi-part geometries do not
I'm currently trying to develop a code that optimizes some parameters within a boundary to maximize another parameter. I need to insert 58 points inside a given boundary arranged based on 5 parameters: dx (distance between points in a row), dy (distance between rows), theta (angle of the rows), b (offset), and s (distance between turbines on the boundary).
To achieve this, I've developed an algorithm that works well for square boundaries. However, it seems to encounter issues with different geometries. After some arrangements are made, I encounter the error:

NotImplementedError: Sub-geometries may have coordinate sequences, but multi-part geometries do not.

Is it possible that the problem arises from the intersection of the line in my code with the boundary occurring more than twice? Here attached is some output generated before the simulation gives the error.
What I did is generate the objective function, then calculate the function for each layout generated (generated with the bounds parameters)
def obj_fun(ga_instance, solution, solution_idx):
    
    dx,dy,theta,b,s = solution

    if np.abs(b) > dx: # penalty function to enforce the constraint on the value of b (logically must be smaller than dx)
        print('z')
        return 1e-10
    
    # Extract layout coordinates from the parameters
    x_coords, y_coords = fun.five_params2coords([dx,dy,theta,b,s], n_turbs, rect_boundaries)
  
    if len(x_coords) != n_turbs: # penalty function to enforce the constraint on the number of turbines --> not necessary but makes the optimization faster. It can however become an issue when too few good solutions are found.
        return 1e-10
  
    # Reinitialize the FLORIS interface with the new layout
    fi.reinitialize(
        layout_x = x_coords,
        layout_y = y_coords,
    )
  
    # Calculate AEP
    aep = fi.get_farm_AEP( # the following parameters are defined outside the function
        freq = freq,
        cut_in_wind_speed = cut_in_ws, 
        cut_out_wind_speed = cut_out_ws,  
    )
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
    plt.scatter(x_coords, y_coords, color='blue')
    plt.title('Optimized Turbine Layout')
    plt.xlabel('X-coordinate (m)')
    plt.ylabel('Y-coordinate (m)')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
    return aep

bounds = [range(int(3.5*D),20*D+10,10), range(int(7.5*D),15*D+10,10), range(-90,91,1), range(-4*D,4*D+10,10), range(int(8*D),20*D+10,10)]

n_var = 5 #number of variables
n_gen = 50
n_parents = 2 # usually between 2 and 5
sol_per_pop = 50 # usually between 10 and 100
n_proc = 8 # number of processors

ga_instance = pygad.GA(
    fitness_func = obj_fun, # objective function
    num_generations = n_gen, # iterations 
    num_parents_mating = n_parents, 
    sol_per_pop = sol_per_pop, # number of solutions per population 
    num_genes = n_var, # number of variables to optimize
    gene_space = bounds, # bounds for the parameters --> the notation with range is necessary --> if you use a list, only the two extreme values are considered 
    # notice that the step is 10 --> this discretizes the variables --> might be useful for the 64 dimensions problem
    
    parent_selection_type = "sss",
    keep_elitism = 1, # means keep only the best solution of the previous generation
    crossover_type = "uniform", # alternative to 'single_point' --> seems more logical
    
    mutation_type = "adaptive", # mutation adapts to the fitness of the solution --> if good solution, low probability of mutation.
    mutation_percent_genes = [60,20], # the first is the probability of mutation of the bad solutions, the second of the good ones
    #mutation_type = "random", # Alternative to adaptive. This however causes good solution to get worse
    #mutation_num_genes = 1, # genes = variables --> after mating, 1 gene is changed  (used only with random mutation type)
    #mutation_by_replacement = True, # to avoid that variables go out of bounds after mutation
    
    suppress_warnings=True,
    parallel_processing=['process', n_proc], # to parallelize the code
)

if __name__ == "__main__": # fundamental for parallelization
    
    start = time.time()
    ga_instance.run()

    solution, solution_fitness, solution_idx = ga_instance.best_solution()
    print(f"\nParameters of the best solution : {solution}")
    print(f'AEP = {solution_fitness/1e9:.2f} GWh')

    end = time.time()
    elapsed_time_seconds = end - start
    elapsed_minutes = int(elapsed_time_seconds // 60)
    elapsed_seconds = int(elapsed_time_seconds % 60)
    print(f'Time elapsed for parallel optimization with {n_proc} cores : {elapsed_minutes} min {elapsed_seconds} sec\n')
    
    dx_opt, dy_opt, theta_opt, b_opt, s_opt = solution
    

    # Save the results in a txt file
    data = {
        'dx opt [m]': dx_opt,
        'dy opt [m]': dy_opt,
        'theta opt [°]': theta_opt,
        'b opt [m]': b_opt,
        's opt [m]': s_opt,
        
        'opt AEP [GWh]': solution_fitness/1e9,
        'time [sec]': elapsed_time_seconds,
        
        'algorithm': 'Genetic algorithm with pyGAD',
        'settings': {
            'num_generations': n_gen,
            'num_parents_mating': n_parents,
            'sol_per_pop': sol_per_pop,
            'bounds': bounds,
            'num CPU': n_proc,
        }
    }

    



    # Store the optimized parameters in a txt file
    file_path = r"C:\FLORIS\ENI_site\Work_folder\[Thesis][PowerFloatingWindFarm]\backup_codici\ppt_e_immagini\optimization_results\prova_bottom_fixed_farm_5param_opt_layout.txt.txt"
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=2)

    ga_instance.plot_fitness()

    # Obtain the optimized turbine coordinates
    x_coords_opt, y_coords_opt = fun.five_params2coords([dx_opt, dy_opt, theta_opt, b_opt, s_opt], n_turbs, rect_boundaries)
    # Plot the optimized turbine layout
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.scatter(x_coords_opt, y_coords_opt, color='blue')
    plt.title('Optimized Turbine Layout')
    plt.xlabel('X-coordinate (m)')
    plt.ylabel('Y-coordinate (m)')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()




And here below the function for realizing the grid:
# Function that finds the intersection between a line and a polygon --> used below
def line_polygon_intersection(angle, point, polygon, D=240):
    
    # Angle in degrees, point as a tuple (x, y), polygon as a shapely Polygon object
    # Output is a list of tuples (x, y) containing the intersection points or None if there is no intersection
    
    # Calculate the direction of the line based on the angle
    segment_length_x = 10*(5*D) # To be tuned depending on the size of the polygon (line in Python means a finite segment) so that the segments intesects the boundary
    segment_length_y = segment_length_x * np.tan(np.radians(angle))

    # Place the segment so that the midpoint is at the given point
    x_mid, y_mid = point
    x_start = x_mid - 0.5 * segment_length_x
    y_start = y_mid - 0.5 * segment_length_y
    x_end = x_mid + 0.5 * segment_length_x
    y_end = y_mid + 0.5 * segment_length_y

    # Define the line using the calculated starting and ending points
    line = LineString([(x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end)])

    # Plot the polygon and the line
    x_bound, y_bound = polygon.exterior.xy
    plt.plot(x_bound, y_bound, color='b')
    plt.plot(*line.xy, color='r')
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')  # Equal aspect ratio
    plt.show()  # Display the plot

    # Check if the line intersects the polygon
    if line.intersects(polygon):
        intersection = line.intersection(polygon)
        if hasattr(intersection, 'coords'):
            return [tuple(coord) for coord in intersection.coords]
        elif hasattr(intersection, 'geoms'):  # Check if it's a multipart geometry
            coords = []
            for geom in intersection.geoms:
                if hasattr(geom, 'coords'):
                    coords.extend([tuple(coord) for coord in geom.coords])
                else:
                    print('Unexpected intersection geometry:', geom)
            return coords
        else:
            print('Unexpected intersection geometry:', intersection)
            return None
    else:
        return None  # No intersection


# Function that extracts the coordinates of the turbines from the 4 parameters --> used below
def params2coords(params, n_turbs_max, rect_boundaries):
    
    # Function that takes as input the 4 parameters that define the regular layout and returns
    # the corresponding coordinates of the turbines
    
    # ATTENTION: works only for a rectangular boundary (it shouldn't be hard to generalize it though)

    # STEPS OF THE INITIALIZATION
    # 1) extract boundary from file and define the polygon
    # 2) define a rotating frame of reference in the center of the polygon
    # 3) check if the straight line from that point and with given slope, intersects the polygon, if not, move to the next iteration remebering this fact
    # 4) if there is intersection, start from the 'start_point' and intialize turbines in that row with logic 0 1 -1 2 -2 3 -3...
    # 5) Once the first row is initialized, the second one is initialized with the same logic but after moving by dy (rotated) towards up or down (logic 0 1 -1 2 -2 3 -3...)
    # 6) This goes on until the number of turbines is reached or the rows don't intersect the polygon anymore (both from bottom and top)

    # Parameters extraction
    dx,dy,theta,b = params
    theta_rad = np.deg2rad(theta)

    # Extract rectangular boundary coordinates from the json file
    x_rect, y_rect = zip(*rect_boundaries)

    # Define values that will matter when initializing the single turbines
    x_rect_max = max(x_rect)
    x_rect_min = min(x_rect)
    y_rect_max = max(y_rect)
    y_rect_min = min(y_rect)

    # Transform the boundaries in a polygon so that geometrical operations can be performed easily
    polygon = Polygon(rect_boundaries)
    # Find the center of the polygon
    x0, y0 = polygon.centroid.xy[0][0], polygon.centroid.xy[1][0]

    # Start_point is the point from which the initialization starts AT EACH NEW ROW 
    start_x = x0
    start_y = y0

    # Initialize the lists of coordinates
    x_coords =[]
    y_coords =[]

    # I define 4 boolean variable that will be used to stop the initialization
    # 'upper_row_no_inters' is turned True when the upper straight line does not intersect the polygon anymore
    # 'bottom_row_no_inters' is turned True when the lower straight line does not intersect the polygon anymore
    # 'left_point_out' is turned True when the points on a row exceed the left boundary of the polygon
    # 'right_point_out' is turned True when the points on a row exceed the right boundary of the polygon
    upper_row_no_inters = False
    bottom_row_no_inters = False
    n_turbs = 0
    is_n_max_reached = False
    m = 1 #Starting from 1 instead than zero allows to generate the desired sequence: 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3.....
    tol=1e-8

    
    while upper_row_no_inters*bottom_row_no_inters==False and is_n_max_reached==False:

        left_point_out = False
        right_point_out = False
        n = 1 #Starting from 1 instead than zero allows to generate the desired sequence: 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3.....

        # Compute the starting point for the next row and add the offset b # ATTENZIONE CHE PER IL PRIMO CASO TUTTO CIò CHE AGGIUNGO A X0 DEVE RISULTARE NULLO 

        start_x = x0 + ((-1)**m)*(m//2) * dy * np.cos(theta_rad+np.pi/2) + ((-1)**m)*(m//2) * b * np.cos(theta_rad) 
        start_y = y0 + ((-1)**m)*(m//2) * dy * np.sin(theta_rad+np.pi/2) + ((-1)**m)*(m//2) * b * np.sin(theta_rad) 
    
        start_point = (start_x,start_y)
    
        # Check that the straight line with slope theta and passing through start_point is intersecting the polygon
        # if not, don't even enter the while loop
        
        intersection_points = line_polygon_intersection(theta, start_point, polygon) # function created by me
        if intersection_points == None:
            
            if m%2!=0:
                upper_row_no_inters = True
            else:
                bottom_row_no_inters = True
            """
            if theta >= 0:
                if start_x < x_rect_min or start_y > y_rect_max:
                    upper_row_no_inters = True
                elif start_x > x_rect_max or start_y < y_rect_min:
                    bottom_row_no_inters = True
                else:
                    print('A') # This appears only if some cases were not considered
            elif theta < 0:
                if start_x > x_rect_max or start_y > y_rect_max:
                    upper_row_no_inters = True
                elif start_x < x_rect_min or start_y < y_rect_min:
                    bottom_row_no_inters = True
                else:
                    print('B')
            else: 
                print('C')
            """
            
        else:
    
            # If the starting point is outside of the polygon, one direction of initializing is unuseful for sure.
            max_x_inters_point = max(x[0] for x in intersection_points)
            min_x_inters_point = min(x[0] for x in intersection_points)

                 
            while right_point_out*left_point_out == False and is_n_max_reached==False:
                
                
                # Compute the new point 
                new_x = start_x + ((-1) ** n) * (n // 2) * dx * np.cos(theta_rad)
                new_y = start_y + ((-1) ** n) * (n // 2) * dx * np.sin(theta_rad)
            
                new_point = Point(new_x,new_y)
                
                # Check if the new point is inside the polygon
                #if polygon.contains(new_point): # is True also if the point is on the border but it has issues with floating points
                if polygon.distance(new_point) < tol: 
                    x_coords = x_coords + [new_x]
                    y_coords = y_coords + [new_y]
                    n_turbs = n_turbs + 1
                    # Check if the max number of turbines is reached
                    if n_turbs == n_turbs_max:
                        is_n_max_reached = True
                
                # if the new point is outside the polygon: put either right_point_out or left_point_out to True
                else:
                    if new_x > max_x_inters_point:
                        right_point_out = True
                    elif new_x < min_x_inters_point:
                        left_point_out = True       
                    """    
                    if theta >= 0:
                        if new_x > x_rect_max or new_y > y_rect_max: 
                            right_point_out = True
                        elif new_x < x_rect_min or new_y < y_rect_min:
                            left_point_out = True
                        elif new_x == x_rect_max or new_y == y_rect_max or new_x == x_rect_min or new_y == y_rect_min:
                            print('coordinata sul bordo')
                        else :
                            print('D') # in questo caso non capisco cosa stia succedendo
                    elif theta < 0:
                        if new_x > x_rect_max or new_y < y_rect_min:
                            right_point_out = True
                        elif new_x < x_rect_min or new_y > y_rect_max:
                            left_point_out = True
                        elif new_x == x_rect_max or new_y == y_rect_max or new_x == x_rect_min or new_y == y_rect_min:
                            print('coordinata sul bordo')
                        else: 
                            print('E')
                    else:
                        print('F')
                    """
                n = n+1
            
        m = m+1
    
    #if n_turbs < n_turbs_max: 
    #    print(f'Only {n_turbs} turbines fit in the area with these 4 parameters: [dx,dy,theta,b]={dx,dy,theta,b}' )
    #elif n_turbs == n_turbs_max:
    #    print(f'Valid guess: 32 turbs fit with these 4 param: [dx,dy,theta,b]={dx,dy,theta,b}')
    #else:
    #    print(f'Too many turbines ({n_turbs}) fit in the area with these 4 parameters: [dx,dy,theta,b]={dx,dy,theta,b}' )

    return x_coords,y_coords,

# Function that extracts the Boundary Grid (regular layout function of 5 parameters) --> uses the function above
def five_params2coords(five_params, n_turbs, rect_boundaries):
    
    # function that receives as input the 5 parameters, the number of turbines and the boundaries of the area
    # and returns the coordinates of the turbines in a regular layout function of those 5 params
    # It uses the function params2coords to built the pattern on a shrunk version of the provided area 
    # --> the distance between the outer and inner area is defined by the parameter 'min_dist_between_turb'
    D = 240 # diameter of the IEA 15MW
    min_dist_between_turb = 3.5*D 

    [dx,dy,theta,b,s] = five_params
    # work in shapely since it is easier with geometries
    polygon = Polygon(rect_boundaries)
    Perimeter = LineString(rect_boundaries)
    # compute the perimeter of the area
    perimeter_length = polygon.length 
    # compute the number of turbines on the border
    n_turbs_border = math.floor(perimeter_length/s)
    
    # Make sure that turbines on the border are lower than the total number of turbines
    if n_turbs_border >= n_turbs:
        print(f'Too many turbines ({n_turbs_border}) on the border. Increase the value of s ({s}).')
        x_coords = [] # decide to leave the array empty so that the AEP should be zero (?)
        y_coords = []
        return x_coords, y_coords
    
    # Otherwise initialize the turbines on the border 
    coords_turbs_border = []
    for i in range(n_turbs_border):
        point = Perimeter.interpolate(i * s)
        point_tuple = (point.x, point.y)
        coords_turbs_border.append(point_tuple)
    
    # compute the number of turbines inside the area
    n_turbs_inside = n_turbs - n_turbs_border

    # Create a buffer around the polygon of a fixed values from each border of the polygon --> chosen value = s
    distance = -min_dist_between_turb
    inner_polygon = polygon.buffer(distance, join_style = 'mitre')

    # extract the coordinates of the inner area
    inner_rect_boundaries = list(inner_polygon.exterior.coords)
    
    # initialize the turbines inside the area with the params2coords function
    x_coords_inside,y_coords_inside = params2coords([dx,dy,theta,b], n_turbs_inside, inner_rect_boundaries)
    coords_turbs_inside = list(zip(x_coords_inside, y_coords_inside))
    
    # merge the two lists of coordinates
    coords_turbs = coords_turbs_border + coords_turbs_inside
    x_coords, y_coords = zip(*coords_turbs)
    
    if len(x_coords) != n_turbs:
        print(f'Too low number of turbines ({len(x_coords)}) fit in the area with these 5 parameters: [dx,dy,theta,b,s]={dx,dy,theta,b,s}')
    else:
        print(f'Valid guess: {len(x_coords)} fit in the area with these 5 parameters: [dx,dy,theta,b,s]={dx,dy,theta,b,s}')
    
    return x_coords, y_coords


Just a heads up that if you want to engage with the NREL team on this, please post in the FLORIS GitHub Discussions: https://github.com/nrel/floris/discussions. That being said, this is probably not specifically a FLORIS question, so SO may end up being the best venue.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

The error can arise if you have multipart geometries:
import shapely.wkt

multigeom = shapely.wkt.loads("MULTIPOLYGON (((30 20, 45 40, 10 40, 30 20)), ((15 5, 40 10, 10 20, 5 10, 15 5)))")

#multigeom.coords
#NotImplementedError: Sub-geometries may have coordinate sequences, but multi-part geometries do not

#You need to use .coords on each part:
for part in multigeom.geoms:
    print(part)
    coords = list(part.boundary.coords)
    print(coords)

    # POLYGON ((30 20, 45 40, 10 40, 30 20))
    # [(30.0, 20.0), (45.0, 40.0), (10.0, 40.0), (30.0, 20.0)]
    # POLYGON ((15 5, 40 10, 10 20, 5 10, 15 5))
    # [(15.0, 5.0), (40.0, 10.0), (10.0, 20.0), (5.0, 10.0), (15.0, 5.0)]

